# How to delete the selected item from both ListView and Firebase database

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used this method for removing the selected Item from the `ListView` in my app. 
But when I come back to my again, the deleted items are getting reappeared.

I want to delete the selected Item from Firebase Database too. How do I do that ? Can anyone suggest me.

```
private void removeItemFromPosition(int position) {

  final int deletePosition = position;
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    MainActivity.this);
  alert.setTitle("Delete");
  alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this post?");

  alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      messages.remove(deletePosition);
      Log.d(TAG, "Messages: " + messages);
      mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
  });

  alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  });
  alert.show();
}
```

In my onCreate() method, I have this:

```
mMessageListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    removeItemFromPosition(position);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the key in an array when you are fetching your data from Firebase in onDataChange(), with index respective to that in your ListView. So When an item in list is clicked you get its position and then in your array at that position you get the key and then delete that from firebase
For Example:

`String key = fetchedDropsList.get(position);
 mRef.child(key).removeValue();`

Hope this helps